# How to pass a value of a variable inside a jquery function into a modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I am new to jquery. I want to transfer a value of a vairable from a JQuery function into a modal. The variable name is applicationName. Below is my jquery code and also mu modal code.

```js
<script>
    $("#btnLink").click(function () {
        var applicationName = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).text();

        $('#ModalPopUp').modal('show');
    })
</script>
```

And Modal code:

```html
div class="modal fade" id="ModalPopUp" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog err-pop" style="">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button id="DivClose" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Attachment List</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="text-align:center;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>File Name</th>
                        <th>File Size</th>
                        <th>Attachment Type</th>
                        <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var app in Model)
                    {
                        foreach (var data in app.FileData)
                        {
                            if (data.ApplicationId == app.ApplicationId)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@data.Name</td>
                                    <td>@data.Size</td>
                                    <td>@data.AttachmentType.Description</td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadAttachment", "Application", routeValues: new { id = data.Id }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-small" })
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Need to define what "into a modal" means in more specific element terms

Comment: Which part of the modal are you trying to put the application name into? And is this a Bootstrap modal, right?

Comment: Hi, I want to put the application name inside the razor statement / the foreach statement

Comment: Where you want to put the applicationName in foreach?<td></td>?Or <tr></tr>?

Comment: Hi @YiyiYou , I want to do something like this: if (data.Name == applicationName)
                            {
                                <tr>

                                    <td>@data.Name</td>
                                    <td>@data.Size</td>
                                    <td>@data.AttachmentType.Description</td>
                                    <td>

Comment: Basically, I want to take the value in the jquery code and use it as a comparison in the if statement.

Comment: You cannot use applicationName in server side code,but you can delete the <tr>s if (data.Name != applicationName),you can compare applicationName and first cell of each  tr,and then change the data in html.I have updated my answer,you can refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use applicationName in server side code,but you can foreach in js,and change the tr in the foreach.Here is a demo:

View(TestApplicationName.cshtml):

```
<button id="btnLink">btnLink</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalPopUp" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog err-pop" style="">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button id="DivClose" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Attachment List</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="text-align:center;">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>File Name</th>
                        <th>File Size</th>
                        <th>Attachment Type</th>
                        <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var app in Model)
                    {
                        foreach (var data in app.FileData)
                        {
                            if (data.ApplicationId == app.ApplicationId)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@data.Name</td>
                                    <td>@data.Size</td>
                                    <td>@data.AttachmentType.Description</td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadAttachment", "Application", routeValues: new { id = data.Id }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-small" })
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
<script>

            $("#btnLink").click(function () {
                //var applicationName = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).text();
                var applicationName = "f21";
                $("tbody tr").each(function (index, data) {
                    if (data.cells[0].innerText != applicationName) {
                        data.remove();
                    }
                })
             

            })
    </script>
```

Models:

```
public class App
    {
        public List<FileData> FileData { get; set; }
        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }

    }
    public class FileData {
        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Size { get; set; }

        public AttachmentType AttachmentType { get; set; }


    }
    public class AttachmentType {
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult TestApplicationName()
        {
            List<App> l = new List<App> {
            new App{  ApplicationId=1, FileData=new List<FileData>{ new FileData {  ApplicationId=1, Id=11, AttachmentType=new AttachmentType {  Description="dsds"},  Name="f11", Size="2"} } },
            new App{  ApplicationId=2, FileData=new List<FileData>{ new FileData {  ApplicationId=2, Id=21, AttachmentType=new AttachmentType {  Description="dsdds"},  Name="f21", Size="2"},new FileData {  ApplicationId=2, Id=22, AttachmentType=new AttachmentType {  Description="dsgterbdds"},  Name="f22", Size="2"} }, },
            new App{  ApplicationId=3, FileData=new List<FileData>{ new FileData {  ApplicationId=3, Id=31, AttachmentType=new AttachmentType {  Description="dggsds"},  Name="f31", Size="2"} } },

            };
            return View(l);
        }
```

Result:

[image]